# Timer code not showing up on my iPhone when launched

Tags: objective-c, xcode, timer

Here goes the code:

```
-(void)timerLabel{

timerLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
timerLabel.text = @"Time: 0";
timerLabel.fontColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
timerLabel.fontSize = 24.0f;
timerLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeRight;
timerLabel.position = CGPointMake(310, 10);
[self addChild:timerLabel];

}
```

Comment: you need to provide a little bit more code.  what class is that you are "addchild"    Should you be using "addsubview"

Comment: You never set the size of the label. (use `frame`)